# incorrect JSON data - Array to Object

Tags: php, arrays, object, routific-api

I am new in php json object. 
I am trying to create below json format from my database table data. Where basically **Visits** is an object. But my object knowledge i very limited so I am stuck into it.

```
"visits": {
  "order_1": {
    "location": {
      "name": "6800 Cambie",
      "lat": 49.227107,
      "lng": -123.1163085
    },
    "start": "9:00",
    "end": "12:00",
    "duration": 10,
    "load": 1,
    "type": "A",
    "priority": "high"
  }
}
```

But I am getting below json format. Which is wrong.

```
{
  "visits": [
    {
      "order_1": {
        "location": {
          "name": "21 Marara Court, ALBANY CREEK QLD 4035",
          "lat": "-37.7044",
          "lng": "145.1006"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "order_2": {
        "location": {
          "name": "Unit 7, 19 O'Connell Street, KANGAROO POINT QLD 4169",
          "lat": "-37.6389",
          "lng": "145.1950"
        }
      }
    },

  ],
  "fleet": {
    "vehicle_1": {
      "start_location": {
        "id": "depot",
        "name": "23 Moverly Rd",
        "lat": -33.9356141,
        "lng": 151.2425993
      },
      "end_location": {
        "id": "depot",
        "name": "23 Moverly Rd",
        "lat": -33.9356141,
        "lng": 151.2425993
      }
    }
  },

}
```

The problem is on `"visits": [` array. But I need object.
So my php code is below:

```
foreach ($orders as $value) {
  $orders2[] = array(
        "order_$i"=> array(
            "location"=> array(
                "name"=> $value['address'],
                "lat"=> $value['lat'],
                "lng"=> $value['long']
            ),
        ),
    );
}

$data = array(
    "visits" => $orders2,
    "fleet"=> array(
        "vehicle_1"=> array(
            "start_location"=> array(
                "id"=> "depot",
                "name"=> "23 Moverly Rd",
                "lat"=> -33.9356141,
                "lng"=> 151.2425993
            ),
            "end_location"=> array(
                "id"=> "depot",
                "name"=> "23 Moverly Rd",
                "lat"=> -33.9356141,
                "lng"=> 151.2425993
            ),

        )
    ),

);
```

It would be better if anyone can give me any idea. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an object with `json_encode` you have to use custom array keys.

Try this:

```
foreach ($orders as $value) {
    $orders2["order_$i"] = array(
        "location"=> array(
            "name"=> $value['address'],
            "lat"=> $value['lat'],
            "lng"=> $value['long']
        ),
     );
}
```

Just for the sake of completeness:

You can also use the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option in `json_encode` or directly use a `StdClass` to force it to get an json object. But in your case the structure was wrong anyway, so the code above should work fine for you.